# How do I extract a single byte from an xmm-register in Asm?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, gnu-assembler

I was learning SSE-instructions and found a weird error with GNU's `as` assembler, when trying to copy a single byte from an xmm-register to `al`:
"Error: operand type mismatch for `pextrb`".

I think my syntax is right, it works perfectly fine with `pextrd`.

```
pextrd $3, %xmm0, %eax  # Works perfectly fine
pextrb $3, %xmm0, %al   # Error: operand type mismatch for 'pextrb'
```

Comment: gcc produces `%eax`. Probably because the result is 0-extended?

Comment: See also [pextrb](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pextrb:pextrd:pextrq): *the default operand size in 64-bit mode for PEXTRB/PEXTRD is 64 bits, the bits above the least significant byte/dword data are filled with zeros*

Comment: @MarcGlisse: yup, Intel thankfully avoided introducing new instructions that require extra work to avoid false dependencies the way `setcc r/m8` does, like `xor %eax,%eax` / `setl %al`.  It would have been a terrible design decision to have PEXTRB/PEXTRW merge into the low byte of RAX instead of zero-extending into the full RAX, with no dependency on the old value.

Answer (score 3):

Marc Glisse is right, it works when using eax instead of al. It is zero-extended, so eax actually contains only the one single byte. Thank you!

```
pextrb $3, %xmm0, %eax
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can directly store the result to memory (in which case it is not zero extended, of course).